# Enable mod_rewrite rules for page not managed by Joomla - 403 forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have a simple issue to resolve. Every time I access one of the URLs explicitly defined in `.htaccess` (used by Joomla), I'm getting `403 Forbidden` message.

Details about my setup:

1. I'm using shared hosting
2. Joomla is installed in the root folder
3. my newly created page is located in `/new/products.php`
4. `.htaccess` is the default one supplied by Joomla with one additional rule: `rewriterule $/new/products^ /new/products.php [R=301,L]`
5. `Options +FollowSymLinks` is commented out, but switching it on doesn't change anything

Each time I access `mysite.com/new/products` I' getting:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /new/products/ on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding `defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Direct Access not allowed.' );`? Also, try `define` instead of `defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I simply removed old site, cleared all Jooml entries in `.htaccess` and did `RewriteBase` to point to my directory. The problem is no more.

Comment: How the `.htaccess` file is rewrite, In my website i have not changed anything in the htaccess file, website works fine yesterday. but now its not working, because there some code `deny access` is available in the .htaccess. my site is hacked?

Comment: Perhaps your admin has changed access rights on your server. That could result in `deny of access`. I suggest post this in separate question, as that way you'll get more attention and people could help you out.